# Error message when trying to start varnish on centos 5.5

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, reverse-proxy, centos5, varnish

I just installed and configured Varnish to work on port 80, and Apache to work on port 8080.
I am trying to start Varnish with the command `service varnish start`, but it gave me this error:

> varnishd dead but pid file exists

I edited this configuration in the `/etc/sysconfig/varnish`:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -u varnish -g varnish \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,1G"
```

This is the content of the default.vcl file:

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 600s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.request != "GET" &&
    req.request != "HEAD" &&
    req.request != "PUT" &&
    req.request != "POST" &&
    req.request != "TRACE" &&
    req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.request != "DELETE") {
      // Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. 
      return (pipe);
  }

  if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
    // We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    return (pass);
  }

  // Remove has_js and Google Analytics cookies.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, 
"(^|;\s*)(__[a-z]+|__utma_a2a|has_js)=[^;]*", "");

  // To users: if you have additional cookies being set by your system 
(e.g.
  // from a javascript analytics file or similar) you will need to add 
VCL
  // at this point to strip these cookies from the req object, otherwise
  // Varnish will not cache the response. This is safe for cookies that 
your
  // backend (Drupal) doesn't process.
  //
  // Again, the common example is an analytics or other Javascript 
add-on.
  // You should do this here, before the other cookie stuff, or by 
adding
  // to the regular-expression above.


  // Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
  // Remove empty cookies.
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }

  if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
    // Not cacheable by default 
    return (pass);
  }

  // Skip the Varnish cache for install, update, and cron
  if (req.url ~ "install\.php|update\.php|cron\.php") {
    return (pass);
  }

  // Normalize the Accept-Encoding header
  // as per: http://varnish-cache.org/wiki/FAQ/Compression
  if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
      # No point in compressing these
      remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
    elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
      set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    }
    else {
      # Unknown or deflate algorithm
      remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
  }

  // Let's have a little grace
  set req.grace = 30s;

  return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_hash {
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    hash_data (req.http.Cookie);
  }
}

// Strip any cookies before an image/js/css is inserted into cache.
sub vcl_fetch {
  if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js)$") {
    // For Varnish 2.0 or earlier, replace beresp with obj:
    // unset obj.http.set-cookie;
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }
}

// Set a header to track a cache HIT/MISS.
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
  }
  else {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}

sub vcl_error {
  // Let's deliver a friendlier error page.
  // You can customize this as you wish.
  set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
  synthetic {"
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
      <style type="text/css">
      #page {width: 400px; padding: 10px; margin: 20px auto; border: 1px 
solid black; background-color: #FFF;}
      p {margin-left:20px;}
      body {background-color: #DDD; margin: auto;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page">
    <h1>Page Could Not Be Loaded</h1>
    <p>We're very sorry, but the page could not be loaded properly. This 
should be fixed very soon, and we apologize for any inconvenience.</p>
    <hr />
    <h4>Debug Info:</h4>
    <pre>Status: "} + obj.status + {"
Response: "} + obj.response + {"
XID: "} + req.xid + {"</pre>
      </div>
    </body>
   </html>
  "};
  return(deliver);
}
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

. . . make sure Varnish isn't running, and if it's not delete the PID file?

Comment: Varnish is not working and whenever i delete the varnish.pid file from `/var/run/` it's recreated again

Comment: @M.B.Asfoor See, now telling us what you've already tried would be something important to put in your *question*:  Varnish is starting and dying - If you want help troubleshooting that you need to give us something to work with (log files are a good start, so is console output when you run Varnish manually from the command line)

Comment: i have added some details in the question i reviewed the logs and didn't find any thing unusual

Answer (score 2):

Check the secret file in /etc/varnish. It must have a value.

Comment: The secret file, or the PID file?  And what should he do once he finds it?

Comment: For the secret file, ensure there is a hash similar to the value seen with a fresh install. This is just a possibility but was the solution for me with identical symptoms.

Comment: Neat article to help, just in case: http://www.michaelphipps.com/how-create-varnish-secret-file

Comment: If it's a hunch it's probably better suited for a comment.